# Optimal and efficient way to examine python lists

Tags: python, performance

I was asked this on an interview this past week, and I didn't have the answer (the correct answer anyways).  Say for instance you have list A which has the following elements [1,3,5,7,9,10] and then you have list B, which has the following elements: [3,4,5,6,7], and you want to know which elements in list B are in list A.  My answer was:

```
for item in listA:
    for item1 in listB:
        if item1 == item:
            put item1 in some third list
```

But I know this is bad, because say listA is one million elements, and listB is a hundred thousand, this solution is just rubbish.

What's the best way to achieve something like this without iteration of both lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest converting them both to sets and doing an intersection:

```
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)
setA.intersection(setB)
```

Edit: Note that this will remove any duplicate elements that were in both lists. So if we had `listA = [1,1,2,2,3]` and `listB = [1,1,2,3]` then the intersection will only be `set([1,2,3])`. Also, for a worst-case estimate, this will be as slow as the list comprehension - `O(n * m)`, where n and m are the respective lengths of the lists. Average case is a far better `O(n) + O(m) + O(min(m,n)) == O(max(m,n))`, however.

Comment: Or make them sets to begin with, and never use lists. Sometimes you need a list, but in my experience it either should be a set all the time, or you do not need the operations sets afford you.

Comment: For the worst case, you mean if there is a hash collision for most of elements ?

Comment: @MatthieuW Yes. Although this is incredibly unlikely in practice.

Comment: By far the best answer, because you took the time to explain the complexity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`set(listA) & set(listB)` is simplest.

Comment: if all the items are hashable

Comment: Yes, which they are in the given data.

Answer (score 1):

Using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and using the [in](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in) operator to test for membership:

```
[i for i in lista if i in listb]
```

would yield:

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

Alternatively, one could use set operations and see what the intersection of both lists (converted to sets) would be.

Comment: this is the most verbose method and i think thats a good thing

Comment: This is just a more concise way of writing OP's version, and suffers from exactly the same problems. It's O(n * m).

Comment: @delnan I was wondering about that myself. While LC will be more efficient that explicit loops, I don't think the order ie. big-O would change (assuming that `in` does some sort of iterations of its own to test for membership)

Comment: Believe me, `in` does what OP's inner loop does. Lists are just arrays, not sorted in general, and documented to only use equality to boot. It *cannot* be faster than linear search, and in fact that is exactly what it does (cf. [`listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b86f3af4746c/Objects/listobject.c#l402) and PyPy's [`listobject.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/885cf902742d/pypy/objspace/std/listobject.py#cl-291)).

Comment: @delnan I wasn't not believing :) you .. but thanks for confirming what I suspected. Sometimes things are implemented more efficiently than I imagine, but not as it appears in this case. Thanks. (hence also my alternative suggestion for sets)

Comment: @JoranBeasley No it's not. Only fools use unordered lists as sets and linear scan as membership checks. Python implementers aren't fools, they use hash tables, rendering membership checks amortized O(1) => intersection is O(max(n, m)) or something like that. An alternative implementation (can't be used for Python's builtin `set` because it has different requirements on the elements) are balanced binary trees, where membership test is O(log n) and intersection is thus O(n log m). See setobject.c starting from line 61.

Comment: @delnan thanks for the info.   I will be sure to keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

well i may as well throw filter in the mix

```
filter(lambda x: x in listb,lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets (preferred):

```
listC = list(set(listA) & set(listB))
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
listC = [i for i in listA if i in listB]
```